# How to return the value from an async function

Tags: javascript

I have an async function that I would like to return a value from and then use.

Within the `updatedStyleSheet` function, I'd like to return the `updated_css` so that I can use it somewhere else.

```
async function updatedStyleSheet() {
  const res = await fetch("./prism.css");
  const orig_css = await res.text();
  let updated_css = orig_css;

  const regexp = /(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/g;
  let cssVars = orig_css.matchAll(regexp);
  cssVars = Array.from(cssVars).flat();

  for (const v of cssVars) {
     updated_css = updated_css.replace(v,   colors[v.slice(6, -1)]);
   };

// return updated_css ?
}
```

If I call this function, I get a Promise object. Rightfully so, since async functions always return a promise.

Could I return the `updated_css` within the `updatedStyleSheet` function and do something like this after?

```
const newSheet = updatedStyleSheet().then(css => css)
```

Then use the `newSheet` variable wherever in my script?

**End Goal**

Take the `updated_css` that contains the text contents of my CSS and use it as an `href` value so the user can download the stylesheet.

**Edit**

I attempted to add an event handler so that all the selected color values would be saved in the stylesheet once the user saves it, but it doesn't seem to work. I know it is still an issue with my understanding of promises as a whole.

**What I did.**

```
const updatedStyleSheet = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("./themes/prism.css");
  const orig_css = await res.text();
  let updated_css = orig_css;

  const regexp = /(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/g;
  let cssVars = orig_css.matchAll(regexp);
  cssVars = Array.from(cssVars).flat();
  console.log(cssVars)

  for await (const variable of cssVars) {
    const trimmedVar = variable.slice(6, -1)
    const styles = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    const value = String(styles.getPropertyValue(`--${trimmedVar}`)).trim()

    updated_css = updated_css.replace(variable, value);
  }
  console.log(updated_css)

  return updated_css
}

const main = async () => {
  const downloadBtn = document.getElementById('download-btn')
  downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const updated_css = updatedStyleSheet()
    downloadBtn.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(updated_css))
    downloadBtn.setAttribute('download', 'prism-theme.css')
  })
}

main()
```

I can't `await` the `updated_css` because it falls into the callback of the click event, which is a new function.

Then I did the following thinking it would work since it was top level.

```
const downloadBtn = document.getElementById('download-btn')
downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const updated_css = await updatedStyleSheet()
  downloadBtn.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(updated_css))
  downloadBtn.setAttribute('download', 'prism-theme.css')
})
```

That gave me the following error `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

Comment: Yes, `css` in the `then` callback would be your returned item but it doesnt return it to the outside you will just get another promise. You cant go from async code and then back to the outside sync code

Comment: `newSheet` is again going to be a `Promise`. As @PatrickEvans said, "You can't go from async code and then back to the outside sync code". However, as you said you want to use it as an href value, you can do that inside `.then()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since you're already using `async/await`, just create a top level `async` function, say `main`, and use the returned `updated_css` content after awating the promise to resolve:

```
async main() {
  const updated_css = await updatedStyleSheet()
  // use css as you please
}

// run program
main()
```

Don't mind the cost of one more function call.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question regarding this answer and adding a click event that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would collapse the promise by using  the .then() function EX:

```
var bar = updatedStyleSheet()
bar.then(updated_css=>{
//logic goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for an async function to return a value (so that you can use this value afterwards), use the `await` keyword:

```
const newSheet = await updatedStyleSheet()
```

However, mind that awaiting blocks the execution until the function returns. This might not be the behaviour you want.